# Preview de arquivo PDF em website desenvolvido com PHP, Jquery e CSS3

Tags: php, jquery, pdf

Vi no website da Dropbox que meus arquivos extensão PDF são exibidos uma prévia da primeira página do arquivo, busquei soluções na internet para o mesmo mas vi que existe apenas modos de incorporar o PDF em iframe ou usando uma URL do google drive para exibi-lo, gostaria de fazer o mesmo em meu website, mas não fazer uso dessas sugestões que exibe tudo, pois são muitos PDF's e ficará pesado o carregamento da tela, gostaria de saber como fazem pra tirar esse print da primeira página do PDF, como é feito no Dropbox. Os arquivos estão com o caminho guardados no banco de dados, os arquivos físicos em uma página de upload, no website faço uso de PHP, jQuery e CSS3.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o [`PDF.js`](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Primeiro baixe o `PDF.js` e pegue todos scripts e adicione ao seu projeto, então na sua página, no `<head>` deve adicionar:

```
<script src="build/pdf.js"></script>
```

Para pegar a primeira página (ou outra qualquer ) use `getPage`

```
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

pdfjsLib.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(function (pdf) {
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
        var scale = 1.5; //Scala inicial desejada, ajuste como quiser

        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        var canvas = document.getElementById('meuCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        page.render({
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport
        });
    });
});
```

E deve existir um canvas na página (ou gerar), com o conteúdo dele:

```
<canvas id="meuCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: gratidão Guilherme.

Comment: Em var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'); não deveria ser var canvas = document.getElementById('meuCanvas'); ?

Comment: @EliseuB. sim, erro de digitação, desculpe. Corrigido ;)